# URI.parse make "scheme" part frozen

Tags: ruby

Could anyone explain me the following weirdness?

```
1.9.3-p286 :029 > u = URI.parse("http://www.nevermind.org")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x007f87499a5c90 URL:http://www.nevermind.org>
1.9.3-p286 :030 > u.component.map {|c| u.send(c).frozen?}
 => [true, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Why for the god sake (only) "scheme" part of the parsed url is frozen?  Looking over URI source did not bring any reasonable answer.

Comment: The source code (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/trunk/lib/uri/generic.rb#L218 ) says that the piece of code which freezes scheme part has been there for ages (more than 10 years). I understand that this doesn't answer your question, I just hope that my comment helps someone else to give the right answer. I personally think that freezing the scheme part has something to do with security, but I can't come up with the scenario of how things could be broken if `@scheme.freeze` weren't there.

Comment: More URI components are frozen now.  In Ruby 2.2.1, "scheme", "userinfo", "port", "query" and "fragment" are all frozen.  "userinfo", "host", and "path" are not frozen.

Comment: This question caused me to ask http://stackoverflow.com/q/31755779/238886

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only reason this exists is because someone forgot to delete something when refactoring. I'm not sure, though. The original comment is just "added URI library", which suggests it was there in the old, separate version of the library, but I don't know where to find that (if it's even still available!) so I doubt this can be answered.