# Does #freeze have a use other than preventing modification?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's [standard *uri* library](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/lib/uri) has many uses of freeze on objects which either can't be modified, or where modification will cause no harm:

```
  user, password = ui.split(':'.freeze, 2)     # from generic.rb
```

String#split won't modify its arguments, and even if it did, the code would work properly (Ruby will use a new instance of ':' on the next call).

Here are some more uses of freeze on objects that can't change (these are all from [generic.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/generic.rb))

```
 if @scheme && @scheme != "ftp".freeze 
 v.delete!("\t\r\n".freeze)
 str << ':'.freeze
```

Why are there so many instances of seemingly needless calls to #freeze?  **Does #freeze have a use beyond preventing modification of its receiver?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here: http://tmm1.net/ruby21-fstrings/

> In Ruby 2.1, "str".freeze is optimized by the compiler to return a single shared frozen strings on every invocation. An alternative "str"f syntax was implemented initially, but later reverted.
>
> Although the external scope of this feature is limited, internally it is used extensively to de-duplicate strings in the VM. Previously, every def method_missing(), the symbol :method_missing and any literal "method_missing" strings in the code-base would all create their own String objects. With Ruby 2.1, only one string is created and shared. Since many strings are commonly re-used in any given code base, this easily adds up. In fact, large applications can expect up to 30% fewer long-lived strings on their heaps in 2.1.
>
> For 2.2, there are plans to expose this feature via a new String#f. There's also a proposal for a magic immutable: string comment to make frozen strings default for a given file.

TL;DR: the Ruby parser treats a string literal with `.freeze` after it differently than a string literal without the `.freeze`. Strings with `.freeze` will not be re-instantiated every time they are used, but instead will come from a global frozen string pool like symbols.

Here is a more in-depth article on the subject: http://josephyi.com/freeze/